# Django Models: global name 'SomeModel' is not defined - same python file

Tags: django, django-models

```
class Employee(models.Model):  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80, db_column=u'NOME', verbose_name=_('Name'))
    def get_jobs(self):        
        jobs_before=Itinerary.objects.select_related('job').\
                    filter(contract__employee=self.id).\
                    filter(start_date__lte=date.today()).order_by('-start_date')
        return jobs_before

 """ a few lines below """
class Itinerary(models.Model):
      contract=ForeignKey(Contract)
      ... some fields
```

Well, I have some odd behavior here.

1 ) The app is runing ok in the development mode with (runsever) but crashes with nginx/guncorn/wsgi.

global name 'Itinerary' is not defined

2) It was working ok for years until yesterday - no changes, just a restart in the server.

3) I can't change the position because Employee has a Contract and contract is a foreignKEy in Itinerary.

Why is the app complaining about a class in the same .py file?

** RESOLVED **
I´ve changed the position of Itinerary in models.py and put it before my Class Employee. Made the Itinerary foreign key using strings as pointed in comments.

Comment: full stacktrace please

Comment: Note that you can use strings for the foreign keys, e.g. `contract=ForeignKey('Contract')`, in which case you can order the models however you like. The code you have pasted isn't enough to explain the error, since `Itinerary` is only used inside the `get_jobs` method.

Comment: @Alasdair I´ve changed the position of Itinerary in models.py using strings for ForeignKey and worked. I just could not explain why this error after 2 years in production and without no reason.